# Conditional expectation of derivative to short-form notation

Tags: measure-theory, expectation

I have a continuous random variable $V_t$ for which I was able to show that

$$\mathbb{E}_t\left[\frac{dV}{dt}\right]=X_t.$$

I now want to write (in short-form notation) $dV_t=X_tdt$. How could I justify this writing? I was feeling pushed towards the Radon Nikodym derivative however I had difficulty with a formal justification. Thank you for thinking about it!